# Topological complexity of circle

Tags: gn.general-topology

In the some of article from [Michael Farber](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiq772cspXTAhXEKJoKHaDxA14QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2Fmath%2F0111197&usg=AFQjCNGsyuehFyRcIq8928HY3GKIqPikJQ&sig2=kDgOiM_B--V35fODJkKMYQ&bvm=bv.152174688,d.d24) that is about topological complexity, I'm stuck in continuity of $S_1$ as follows:
Define $U_1 ⊂ S^1 \times S^1$
as $U_1 = \{(A, B); A \neq -B\}$ .A continuous motion planning over $U_1$ is given by the map $S_1: U_1 → PS^1$ which moves $A$ towards $B$ with constant velocity along the unique shortest arc connecting $A$ to $B$.
Equip the path space $PS^1$ with compact-open topology,i can't understand why $S_1$ is continuous!
For more information you can refer to My [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/246784/applications-of-topological-complexity-of-configuration-space)
Can somebody halp me?

Thanks.

Comment: @MarkGrant could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then the compact open topology on $PX$ is metrizable, and is induced by the metric  $$\rho (\gamma, \omega) =\operatorname {sup}\{ d (\gamma (t), \omega (t) )\mid t\in I\}. $$

Knowing this, most people would take continuity of the map you describe as self-evident. If you want a proof, however, it shouldn't be too hard to write one using the  $\epsilon$-$\delta $ definition of continuity.

Comment: Consider two point $(A,A')$ and $(B,B')$ such that they close together as follows  : 
fix antipodal $(z,-z)$, let $(A,A')$ be on left arc $(z,-z)$ and $(B,B')$ be on right arc $(z,-z)$ such that $d(A,a),d(B,a) < \epsilon/2$ and  $d(A',-a),d(B',-a) < \epsilon/2$, now by defination of $U_1$, two path $U_1(A,A')$ and $U_1(B,B')$ are not close together and it means instabilities of $U_1$.  
I don't know where I made a mistake!

Comment: I think you are perhaps misunderstanding the $\epsilon $-$\delta$ definition of continuity, which says "for every $\epsilon$..there is a $\delta $..."

Comment: The instability is important for motion planing now I find two points that close Together and we expect $U_1$ give us two path s.t they are close but it isn't.

Comment: I'm afraid your $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s are still garbled. Let me put it this way: if $(A,B) $ is a non-antipodal pair and the shortest arc from $A $ to $B $ is clockwise, then the same will be true for any sufficiently close pair $(A',B') $.

Comment: Consider line $zz'$ as diameter of circle, now we have left arc $zz'$ and right arc $zz'$. $(A,B)$ is on right arc $zz'$ and it is very close to (z,z') and $(A',B')$ is on left arc $zz'$ and it is very close to $(z,z')$ so short  arc $A$ to $B$ is  clockwise but short arc $A'$ to $B'$ is non clockwise.

Comment: Then $(A',B') $ is not sufficiently close to $(A,B) $, so make it closer (pick a smaller $\delta $). I recommend you revise the definition of continuity. I would be happy to continue by email if necessary.